# Sending Slack message via windows Curl

Tags: c++, curl, slack-api

I'm try to send Slack messages with Slack API and curl command on C++ Console Application but I can’t solve this error due to String type:

**Curl command (this command successfully send a message)**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" --data "{\"text\":\"A New Program Has Just Been Posted!!!\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/{API_KEY}
```

**C++ code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string command = "curl -X POST -H \"Content - type:application / json\" --data \"{\"text\":\"A New Program Has Just Been Posted!!!\"}\" https://hooks.slack.com/services/{API_KEY}";
    system(command.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

**As you can see on this picture I can't send message (I need to see OK):**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more escaping. You've escaped the shell `"`s, but not the JSON `"`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string command = "curl -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" --data \"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"A New Program Has Just Been Posted!!!\\\"}\" https://hooks.slack.com/services/{API_KEY}";
    system(command.c_str());
}
```

Just like `\"` is an escaped quote, `\\` is an escaped backslash. So a "double-escape" looks like `\\\"`. Yuck!

Since C++11 this may (or may not) be clearer using raw string literals, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string command = R"(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"text\":\"A New Program Has Just Been Posted!!!\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/{API_KEY})";
    system(command.c_str());
}
```

*(I have also corrected your Content-Type header.)*

In any case, I suggest you use *libcurl* rather than executing shell commands.

Comment: Yes I need more escaping but how can I do that correct way?